# Send a PUT request with a file and custom headers

Tags: http, delphi

I am stuck at a problem.

I need to upload a file (a CSV file) to a server by using Delphi. The server have certain requirements that must be followed :

> - The request must be an HTTP PUT request.
> - Must contain the Client ID in the URL request, like this : `example.com/upload/{Client ID}` (`{Client ID}` would be replaced).
> - Must contain the future file name that will be received also in the URL after the client ID, like this : `example.com/upload/{Client ID}/{Future File Name}` (`{Future File Name}` would be replaced), which can be different from your local file name.
> - The API Key must be in the request header (header name: `x-api-key`). Example : `lXViWTzFic9sM8qe9Ew7JME8xTdBAOMJHdIjK7XkjQ00OWr`.

I could do this in CURL, like this example : (Client ID : `d32krpq`, and Future file name : `20181023_update.csv`)

```
curl -v -X PUT https://example.com/upload/d32krpq/20181023_update.csv --upload-file 20181023_update.csv --header "x-api-key: lXViWTzFic9sM8qe9Ew7JME8xTdBAOMJHdIjK7XkjQ00OWr"
```

How to achieve this using Delphi components (using either `TNetHttpClient` or `TRESTClient`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Delphi, sending multiple fields (files, custom headers, body fields, ...) in your `PUT` request is possible in both HTTP client frameworks:

In `TNetHTTPClient` through the method `Put()`, you can use the overloaded function with the local file path's string parameter. And in the function's optional parameter of `TNetHeaders` object, you specify your custom header parameters.

`TNetHeaders` is a dynamic array of the `TNameValuePair` record.

So, you have to create a dynamic array of `TNameValuePair`, then you create an instance of the `TNameValuePair` record with your API key and add it to the dynamic array.

With the exception that in `TNetHTTPClient`, you have to specify the URL segments parameter directly in your URL's request by yourself.

And finally, you call the `Put()` method with your file path's string and `TNetHeaders` objects, like this example:

```
procedure TForm1.PutFile;
var 
  LHTTP: TNetHTTPClient;
  LHeaders: array of TNameValuePair;
begin 
  SetLength(LHeaders, 1);
  LHeaders[0] := TNameValuePair.Create('x-api-key', 'lXViWTzFic9sM8qe9Ew7JME8xTdBAOMJHdIjK7XkjQ00OWr');

  LHTTP := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    LHTTP.Put('https://example.com/upload/d32krpq/20181023_update.csv', 'C:/MyFile.csv', nil, LHeaders);
  finally
    LHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

For the REST Client library, you can simply use the `TRESTRequest.AddFile()` function to add a file, and you can use the `AddParameter()` function to add any custom fields as a body, an URL segment or a header parameter.

Another advantage in `TRESTClient` is that you can use a base URL or a resource where you define URL segments, like `"example.com/upload/{Client ID}/{Future File Name}"`.

Drop the components `TRESTClient`, `TRESTRequest`, and `TRESTResponse` on the form, set the `TRESTClient.BaseURL` to your upload server, and write your code. Like in this example:

```
procedure TForm1.PutFile;
begin 
  try
    try
      RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPUT; 
      RESTRequest1.AddFile('File1', 'C:\MyFile.csv', TRESTContentType.ctTEXT_CSV);

      // Adding the parameters to be included in the URL
      RESTRequest1.AddField('Client ID', 'd32krpq', pkURLSEGMENT);
      RESTRequest1.AddField('Future File Name', '20181023_update.csv', pkURLSEGMENT);

      // Adding a header parameter
      RESTRequest1.AddField('x-api-key', 'lXViWTzFic9sM8qe9Ew7JME8xTdBAOMJHdIjK7XkjQ00OWr', pkHTTPHeader); 

      RESTRequest1.Execute; 
    except
      ShowMessage('Uploading failed'); 
    end;
  finally
    ShowMessage(RESTRequest1.Response.Content); // here you can see your server's response
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You describe `TMultipartFormData`, but that would send a `multipart/form-data` encoded request, which is a very different format than what the OP needs. And your example doesn't demonstrate `TMultipartFormData` anyway.  So I would suggest just dropping that from your description.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau for catching that, we mentionned the `TMultipartFormData` for illustrating some abilities of the `TNetHttpClient`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach using Indy's `TIdHTTP` component:

```pascal
FS := TIdReadFileExclusiveStream.Create('20181023_update.csv');
try
  IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['x-api-key'] := 'lXViWTzFic9sM8qe9Ew7JME8xTdBAOMJHdIjK7XkjQ00OWr';
  IdHTTP1.Put('https://example.com/upload/d32krpq/20181023_update.csv', FS);
finally
  FS.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau but Indy components have no built-in support for HTTPS and require you to install and deploy OpenSSL library, that's why I opted for either `TRESTClient` or `TNetHttpClient`.

Comment: Technically, Indy can use any TLS library you want, as long as you have an SSLIOHandler class to wrap its API. OpenSSL is just the default.